# C# - dll event handler

Tags: c#, events, dll, handler

I am setting a .dll file to create a new form and a new button, but i want that button to do something. Is it possible to create a event handler in a dll file?

```
public static byte sbuton( string er, int by,int re)
{
    Form fg = new Form();
    fg.Show();
    Button b1 = new Button();
    fg.Controls.Add(b1);
    b1.Text = er;
    b1.Location = new Point(by, re);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code that creates a form with a button in it.
When I try to create a new event handler, as I would in a form, I get this error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property".

```
  public static byte sbuton( string er, int by,int re)
    {
        Form fg = new Form();
        fg.Show();
        Button b1 = new Button();
        fg.Controls.Add(b1);
        b1.Text = er;
        b1.Location = new Point(by, re);
        b1.Click += new EventHandler(b1_click);
    }
```

private void b1_click(object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
    }

This is the code from the form where I want use the dll

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("add") && richTextBox1.Text.Contains("buton") && richTextBox1.Text.Contains("text"))
    {
        form.sbuton("buton", 10, 10);
    }
}
```

This creates a button, but nothing happens when the button is clicked, because no event handler is assigned to it in the .dll file.
And also,sorry for the bad english,it is not my native language.

What can i do?
 Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860370/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what the context is. Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's difficult to provide a really good answer.

But in your example, it appears that your event handler is in the same DLL (and I assume, the same class) as the `sbuton()` method. If that's the case, then all you need to do in order to use the event handler is make it a `static` method:

```
private static void b1_click(object sender , EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Now, since you didn't post any of the code in the method, never mind the full context, it's not certain that would work. I.e. if there is a good reason for that method being a non-static method, then you will have to subscribe the event handler by referring to the method with a reference to an *actual instance* of the containing class. If that's the case, then the question commenter Daniel Kelley suggests, [An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860370/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-property), may turn out to be appropriate for your needs after all.

Finally, note that none of this has anything to do with the code being in a DLL. You would have run into this same problem had your `sbuton()` method been in the same project from which you're calling it.

Comment: Yes,thanks.The sbuton() method is in the same DLL and in the same class.I just made my b1 EventHandler static as well and now it works just fine.Sorry for bad question,is my first on this forum.Thanks for making time to help me!